# VBA array loop not using last element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have been staring at this code for hours now and wondering why it just isn't behaving. I need someone sane to look at this and tell me where I am going wrong, please.

I am looking to seed an array with elements in a pattern. I have started with adding an "x" to each element in a row. except the first and the last

As I know the row I am working on I have omitted to the loop that runs through the rows of the array and am working solely on a loop that runs through the columns.

I want to leave element (0,0) blank for now as I will put a name in there so I am starting the loop at 1 to the upper bound.

I want to add the pattern as a string to the last element in the row.

So this should generate 7 elements:
"",x,x,x,x,x,xxxxx

I dimension the array 0 to 3 and 0 to 6 which gives me 4 rows and 7 elements in each row

I start the loop at 1 to leave (0,0) blank which means it should loop 6 times as I am asking it to go 1 below the ubound (1-5) adding an "x" to elements (0,1) through (0,5)

As each loop runs I should be concatenating the "x" together to create the long string.

All seems logical. Does not work the code below outputs:
"",x,x,x,x,x,""

```
NumberOfPatterns = 3
PatternLoc = 6

ReDim PatternArray(0 To NumberOfPatterns, 0 To PatternLoc)

For j = 1 To UBound(PatternArray, 2) - 1

    PatternArray(0, j) = "x"  ' xxxxxx
    PatternArray(0, PatternLoc) = PatternArray(0, PatternLoc) & PatternArray(0, j)
Next
```

Please tell me what I missing?

Edit:

In response to the comment that it works, when I watch the loop using the debugger it seems to but when I paste the array to a sheet it doesnt

```
Sheets("Test1").Select

Set pasteDestination = Range("AX2")
pasteDestination.Resize(UBound(PatternArray, 1), UBound(PatternArray, 2)).Value = PatternArray
```

Edit 2:

So I have found a workaround. But I still don't know why! When I paste back to the sheet if I add + 1 to the second dimension it pastes correctly... is this a bug?

```
Sheets("Test1").Select

Set pasteDestination = Range("AX2")
pasteDestination.Resize(UBound(PatternArray, 1), UBound(PatternArray, 2) + 1).Value = PatternArray
```

Comment: your code works for me: `PatternArray` row 0 is :`Void,"x","x","x","x","x","xxxxx"`

Comment: Do you have an `Option Base 0` or  `Option Base 1` somewhere in your module? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606203/case-in-sensitive-dictionary/31613540#31613540

Comment: I haven't altered the Option Base anywhere

Comment: " which means it should loop 6 times" you are looping from `1 to UBound(PatternArray, 2) - 1` which is `1 To (6-1)` which is `1 to 5` so why do you expect it to look 6 times?

Comment: Hi Joe, thats just a mistype. you are right it should be 'loop 5 times'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this test function helps you to identify how stepping through two-dimension array in VBA script. Each row has a character value.

```
Public Sub TestArrLoop()
    Dim NumberOfPatterns As Long
    Dim PatternLoc  As Long
    Dim PatternArray() As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim str As String

    NumberOfPatterns = 3
    PatternLoc = 6
    ReDim PatternArray(0 To NumberOfPatterns, 0 To PatternLoc) As String

    For j = 0 To UBound(PatternArray, 1)
        PatternArray(j, 0) = LCase(Chr(65 + j)) ' a,b,c,..
        For idx = 1 To UBound(PatternArray, 2) - 1
            PatternArray(j, idx) = Chr(65 + j) ' A,B,C,..
            PatternArray(j, PatternLoc) = PatternArray(j, PatternLoc) & PatternArray(j, idx)
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print "Rows: " & LBound(PatternArray, 1) & "-" & UBound(PatternArray, 1) & ", Cols: " & LBound(PatternArray, 2) & "-" & UBound(PatternArray, 2)
    For j = 0 To UBound(PatternArray, 1)
        str = ""
        For idx = 0 To UBound(PatternArray, 2)
            If idx > 0 Then str = str & ","
            str = str & PatternArray(j, idx)
        Next
        Debug.Print "Row " & j & ": " & str
    Next

    ' Copy array to sheet, resize arguments are 1..n value
    ' it does not allow a value of 0.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rRange As Range
    Set ws = Application.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Set rRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(14, 1), ws.Cells(14 + UBound(PatternArray, 1), 1 + UBound(PatternArray, 2)))
    Set rRange = ws.Range("A14")
    Set rRange = rRange.Resize(UBound(PatternArray, 1) + 1, UBound(PatternArray, 2) + 1)
    rRange.Value = PatternArray
End Sub
```

VBA debug screen should display this

```
Rows: 0-3, Cols: 0-6
Row 0: a,A,A,A,A,A,AAAAA
Row 1: b,B,B,B,B,B,BBBBB
Row 2: c,C,C,C,C,C,CCCCC
Row 3: d,D,D,D,D,D,DDDDD
```

**Edit** Added an array copied to worksheet range

Comment: Hi thanks for putting the time into your answer but it doesn't really answer my question. I am looking for an explanation as to why my code is behaving the way it does. Especially as I am seeing a discrepancy between the code editor and the pasted array. Did you try my code or did you just write your own?

Comment: @Mark added copy-to-worksheet, resize function does not allow a value of 0 you must use 1..n expand values. It is a reason you actually need to do +1 for both row and column axis.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. When you load an array into a range it also starts as 1. Thank you, my mind is at ease now.