# ActiveDocument.Selection.PasteSpecial error: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to write VBA code in Excel to update a Word report.

I am copying pieces of code from Stack Overflow and adapting it.

All of my code is working, I tried it separately, but this line:

```vb
ActiveDocument.Selection.PasteSpecial
```

It gives the following error code:

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Full code:

```vb
Sub UpdateReport()
'
' UpdateReport Macro
' Update the monthly ITCV report
'

'
    Dim wd As Object
    Dim ObjDoc As Object
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim originalImage As InlineShape
    Dim Lines(1 To 8) As Long
    Lines(1) = 103
    Lines(2) = 107
    Lines(3) = 109
    Lines(4) = 110
    Lines(5) = 115
    Lines(6) = 116
    Lines(7) = 117
    Lines(8) = 121
    FilePath = "C:\Users\nmoesen\Desktop"
    FileName = "Test.docx"

    'check if template document is open in Word, otherwise open it
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wd Is Nothing Then
        Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
    Else
        On Error GoTo notOpen
        Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents(FileName)
        GoTo OpenAlready
notOpen:
        Set ObjDoc = wd.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & FileName)
    End If

OpenAlready:
    On Error GoTo 0

    'initialise loop
    
    For i = LBound(Lines) To UBound(Lines)
    
        'set value to generate correct chart
        Sheets("Calculations").Range("AE2").Value = Lines(i)
        
        'copy chart from Excel
        Sheets("Calculations").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy

        Set originalImage = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(i)
        Dim imageControl As ContentControl
        If originalImage.Range.ParentContentControl Is Nothing Then
            Set imageControl = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlPicture, originalImage.Range)
        Else
            Set imageControl = originalImage.Range.ParentContentControl
        End If

        Dim imageW As Long
        Dim imageH As Long
        imageW = originalImage.Width
        imageH = originalImage.Height
        originalImage.Delete
    
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark" & i).Select
   
        ActiveDocument.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
          DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
          Placement:=wdInLine, _
          DisplayAsIcon:=False
        
        With imageControl.Range.InlineShapes(i)
            .Height = imageH
            .Width = imageW
        End With
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveDocument` when you have already defined `ObjDoc` as the document you need to work with?

Comment: I will try to use that, and see if it helps! Edit: Just tried changing it to ObjDoc, got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is rather inconsistent and I initially got distracted by your confusion of whether you are using early or late binding and misread your code.

`ActiveDocument.Selection.PasteSpecial` should actually be `wd.Selection.PasteSpecial`. `Selection` is a member of `Application` not `Document`.

However, as you appear to be pasting into a bookmarked location your code should actually be:

```
'    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark" & i).Select
'
'    ActiveDocument.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
'    DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
'    Placement:=wdInLine, _
'    DisplayAsIcon:=False

    If ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Bookmark" & i) then
        ObjDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark" & i).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
        DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End if
```

If you are using late binding you need to be consistent and declare `originalImage As Object`. If you are using early binding you need to be clear about which library your object type is from, so you should declare `originalImage As Word.InlineShape`

EDIT: You can find an explanation of early and late binding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789713/5211752)

FURTHER EDIT: the code above is correct and should work. It would help you if you also declare `ObjDoc As Word.Document` rather than `ObjDoc As Object` as this will give you access to Intellisense.

You also have an undeclared variable in your code so you should add `Dim i As Long` to your variable declarations. You can avoid these issues by adding Option Explicit at the top of the code module. This will prevent your code from compiling when you have undeclared variables. To add this automatically to new modules open the VBE and go to Tools | Options. In the Options dialog ensure that Require Variable Declaration is checked.

FURTHER EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:
Having re-read your code I am guessing that the bookmarked location you are attempting to paste to contains a picture content control. This would explain the "This command is not available" as Paste Special is not available for a picture content control.

Further assuming that this is the picture content control to which the object named 'imageControl' refers you could rework your code as follows:

```
   '    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark" & i).Select
   '
   '    ActiveDocument.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
   '    DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
   '    Placement:=wdInLine, _
   '    DisplayAsIcon:=False
   '
   '    With imageControl.Range.InlineShapes(i)
   '        .Height = imageH
   '        .Width = imageW
   '    End With
   
   imageControl.Range.Paste
   With imageControl.Range.InlineShapes(1)
      .Chart.ChartData.BreakLink
      .Height = imageH
      .Width = imageW
   End With
```

This will result in the content control containing a chart rather than an image, but the chart will no longer be linked to its data.

In line with my previous comments `Dim imageControl As ContentControl` should be `Dim imageControl As Word.ContentControl`. It is good to get into the habit of always specifying which library your object type is from as some objects exist in multiple libraries, e.g. `Selection`.

As a (hopefully) final point, `With imageControl.Range.InlineShapes(i)` would error as a picture content control can only contain one `InlineShape` and `i` goes from 1 to 8.

Comment: @Michthan - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi, I edited the parts you said and changed all references of ActiveDocument to ObjDoc. Also I declared originalImage as Word.InlineShape. Now he gives an error on everything within the If statement This command is not available. I don't really know what early or late binding is. So I just copy, paste and adapt until it works.

Comment: I am of work now and will change it tomorrow and if it works, I will accept your answer. Thanks for all the work!