# Excel VBA to use a Filter when Searching through Hundreds of Files in a Folder

Tags: excel, vba, search, filter, directory

Is there a way in VBA to filter down searches? I'm looking to count specific files that were created "today" and "yesterday" only. The problem is, the folder that it's searching contains hundreds of files from years ago and it takes forever. Is there a way to have the code just search through a specific time frame like 2 days or a week?

```
Sub FindFiles()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim Yesterday As Date
Dim Today As Date
Dim File As String
Dim i As Long

MyFolder = "C:\MyReports\"
Yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
Today = Date

i = 0

For Each file In Dir(MyFolder)
If File.DateCreated >= yesterday And File.DateCreated <= today Then
    i = i + 1
End If
Next file

Msgbox i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried running that code? Where did you get it?

Comment: `For Each file In Dir(MyFolder)` is not valid VBA code

Comment: The posted code will not even compile! So, how do you know it will take forever?

Comment: Using `Dir` and `FileDateTime` takes 1s on my laptop to loop over 4000 files.

Comment: You could use PowerQuery to get all files from a folder and then filter by extension and date created.

Comment: @FunThomas: Right, `Dir` is fast. But `FileDateTime` returns `DateLastModified` and OP looks for `dateCreated` which might be the same but does not have to be. How would you retrieve that date without using `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. Because `Scripting.FileSystemObject` can slow down code by my experience

Comment: @Storax. You are right, havn´t had a closer look, just wanted to point out that it doesn´t take forever. For creation date, you need the FileSystemObject - which is a little slower, took 5s on my computer. Still nothing to worry about.

Comment: @FunThomas: Thanks, so I am right. Using `Scripting.FileSystemObject` for accessing files like that slows down code. Of course, in this case nothing to worry about, but IMHO 5s instead of 1s is significant.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by others, your posted code will not compile ... the [Dir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) function doesn't work like that.

There is no magic way to filter files, but using the following is extremely fast even if you have thousands of files in the relevant folder.

It uses the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198742(v=technet.10)) to iterate the files in the folder ... there are two versions:

**Early binding**

You need to add a reference to the 'Microsoft Scripting Library' for this version (in the VBE: Tools > References then check against 'Microsoft Scripting Library' and OK). And, as performance is a consideration for you, then this version may well be faster.

```
Sub FindFiles()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim Yesterday As Date, Today As Date

MyFolder = "C:\MyReports\"
Yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
Today = Date

Dim i As Long
Dim oFiles As Scripting.Files
Dim oFile As Scripting.File
With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set oFiles = .GetFolder(MyFolder).Files
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        If oFile.DateCreated >= Yesterday And oFile.DateCreated <= Today Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next oFile
End With

MsgBox i

End Sub
```

**Late binding**

You do not need to add the reference for this version but, if you decide to amend or add to this code, you will not get 'Intellisense' for the FileSystemObject objects and members.

```
Sub FindFiles()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim Yesterday As Date, Today As Date

MyFolder = "C:\MyReports\"
Yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)
Today = Date

Dim i As Long
Dim oFiles As Object
Dim oFile As Object
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFiles = .GetFolder(MyFolder).Files
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        If oFile.DateCreated >= Yesterday And oFile.DateCreated <= Today Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next oFile
End With

MsgBox i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think one can use [Early binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49789713/6600940) in this case for `Microsoft Scripting` quite safely. As this library has not changed for ages you will not run into any version conflicts.

Comment: I agree completely ... my concern was more about whether the questioner was willing / able to add the reference to FSO ... hence wanted to provide an option (i.e. late binding) if they did / could not

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function. It uses the powerful `Robocopy` (Robust File Copy for Windows), in a `Command Prompt` command line:

```
Function CreatedFiles(strFoldPath As String, oldDate As String, recentDate As String) As Variant
  Dim strCmd As String, arrFiles, strText As String
  Const strLog As String = "C:\test\FolderList.txt" 'the file to keep the returned files name
  If Dir(strLog) = "" Then CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile strLog
  
  strCmd = "Robocopy """ & strFoldPath & """ NULL /FP /L /MaxAge:" & oldDate & " /MinAge:" & _
                              recentDate & " /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS /NS /S /log:""" & strLog & """"
  shell "cmd /c " & strCmd, vbMinimizedNoFocus
  strText = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strLog, 1).ReadAll

  Dim strangeStr As String: strangeStr = Mid(strText, 3, 6) 'strange (non ASCII) characters in front of each name...
  CreatedFiles = filter(Split(VBA.Replace(strText, strangeStr, ""), vbCrLf), "\")
End Function
```

The used parameters and their meaning (in the above function command line):

```
'NULL - No data will be sent (copy) anywhere
'/FP - include full files pathname
'/L - Only list, don't copy or delete any file!
'/NC - No class. No log file classes
'/NDL - No directory list. don't log directory names
'/NJH -  No Job Header
'/NJS - No Job Summary
'/NS - No Size - don't log file sizes
'/S - copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones
'/LOG:file - output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log)
 '/LOG+:file - output status to LOG file (append to existing log)

'good to also be known:
' /MAXLAD:n - MAXimum Last Access Date - exclude files unused since n
' /MINLAD:n - MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n
```

It can be called/tested in the next way:

```
Sub testModifiedFiles()
  Dim strFoldPath As String: strFoldPath = "C:\Your folder to be processed" 'please use here the real folder path!
  Dim oldDate As Date: oldDate = DateSerial(2023, 7, 2) '07/02/2023
  Dim recentDate As Date: recentDate = Date + 1 'today (+ 1 = inclusively)
  Dim arr
  arr = CreatedFiles(strFoldPath, Format(oldDate, "yyyymmdd"), Format(recentDate, "yyyymmdd"))
  Debug.Print Join(arr, "|") 'just to see the respective files and check (only to validate the function...)
  Debug.Print "Number of files created in the above time interval: " & UBound(arr) + 1 '+ 1 because arr is a zero based type...
End Sub
```

To only return the number of files, the code can be simpler. I thought that returning an array of occurrences my be better. It can be adapted to also copy/move/delete the grabbed files.

Now it searches in the main folder **and its subfolders**, but it can be adapted to return only from the main folder, or as many subfolders levels you need.

Besides the meaning of each (used in the above command line) parameters/options, you can see all of them, simple typing "robocopy /?" in Command Prompt...

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

One more:

```vb
Sub LatestFiles()

    Dim arr, el, t, fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    'filenames only, sorted desc by create time, skip directories
    arr = ShellOutput("cmd.exe /c ""dir /b  /o-d /tc /a:-d  C:\Temp\*.*"" ")

    For Each el In arr
        If Len(el) > 0 Then
            t = fso.getfile("C:\Temp\" & el).datecreated
            If t < (Date - 30) Then Exit For 'for example ,if you want the last month only...
            Debug.Print el, t
        End If
    Next el

End Sub

'Run a shell command, returning the output as an array of lines
Public Function ShellOutput(sCmd As String)
    Dim txt
    txt = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(sCmd).StdOut.readall()
    ShellOutput = Split(txt, vbCrLf)
End Function
```